# Redirect keyboard input to unfocused program

Tags: linux, ssh, redirection, raspbian, stdin

While one program is focused (a full screen web browser) I want to pass keyboard input to another unfocused program (an ssh terminal) in Raspbian/Pi3.

Answer (score 1):

A basic method (Openbox 3.5.2, Raspbian, Pi3).
Edit rc.xml to include a window focus keybinding, e.g.

```
<keybind key="W-x">
  <action name="PreviousWindow">
    <finalactions>
      <action name="Lower"/>
      <action name="FocusToBottom"/>
      <action name="Focus"/>
    </finalsctions>
   </action>
</keybind>
```

The key-binding works with one web browser window & one terminal window.
1: Focus (Alt-Tab) the terminal.
2: Toggle key-binding key (W-x) to focus the terminal window and hide it below the browser window.